# How to compile java files with jar files

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I have a java project which imports several jar libraries. Now I want to run it on a unix machine. There is no java IDE available so i need to use commands like -javac. But I don't know how to compile .java file with .jar files. I put the .java file and .jar files in the same folder, for example, java/com/Tstream: Tstream.java, twitter4j-core.jar, twitter4j-stream.jar, twitter4j-async.jar. Any suggestions?

Comment: ye, but still i got confused.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `javac` tool with `-classpath` (`-cp`) option

```
javac -classpath twitter4j-core.jar;twitter4j-stream.jar;twitter4j-async.jar java/com/Tstream/Tstream.java
```

File tree should be

```
/twitter4j-core.jar  
/twitter4j-async.jar  
/twitter4j-stream.jar  
/java/com/Tstream/Tstream.java
```

Comment: twitter4j-core.jar should not be in the same folder with Tstream.java?

Comment: @Li' No, they can be in different folders. Do you still have the problem?